# Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libarcore_sdk_c.so" not found

Tags: android, android-studio, arcore

I am developing an AR Core app (with Android Studio) and this error occurs spontaneously some times. I have searched on internet and I have found that this is a normal bug that happens sometimes and that it's solved but I am facing this bug now. I have implemented this version of AR Core.

```
   implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.25.0'
   implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.17.1'
   implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:assets:1.17.1'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks :)

Comment: have you had a look at this https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/851

Comment: Yes, I have the library :( I have the library in a folder called "arm64-v8a"

Comment: and did you check the device cpu architecture

Comment: If you mean running this command `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi` , yes and it says "arm64-v8a"

Comment: let me check on my device will get back to you

Comment: i suggest you use version 1.15 which is identical to this and is open source see if that works . because since it is not open source the version 1.17.1 there aint much resource available

Comment: Thank you very very much! I will use that version :D